# Is there a VB.NET-Like operator in C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I am rewriting a vb.net app and I can't claim to be great with vb. I need to write this equivilent in C#:

```
Dim bigList = (From gme In dtx.gmc_message_elements 
              Where gme.element_key_name Like "*email" _
              Or gme.element_key_name Like "*web" 
              Or gme.element_key_name Like "*both" _
              Select gme.element_key_name Distinct).ToList()
```

I have so far:

```
var bigList = (from gme in dtx.gmc_message_elements 
               where gme.element_key_name Like "*email" 
               || gme.element_key_name Like "*web" 
               || gme.element_key_name Like "*both" 
               select gme.element_key_name).FirstOrDefault().ToList();
```

As you can see I am not sure what the equivalent of the like operator is. I ran this through a couple code converters and they constantly threw errors.

Comment: What is the source you're querying? `.Where(x => x.EndsWith("email");` might be appropriate.

Comment: There's no `Like` operator in C#, in this case you can use `String.EndsWith`(if this is `Linq-To-Objects`), otherwise you need to use regex or `SqlMethods.Like`( if it's `Linq-To-Sql` ).

Comment: This question is not a duplicate, this concerns converting the VB.NET `Like` operator to a C# equivalent whereas the other question is the SQL `LIKE` operator, different things...

Comment: @Robert: it's at the top of your post (perhaps you need to refresh)

Comment: This is not a duplicate as stated, for the reason Lukazoid mentions. This is about a different operator altogether.

Comment: It is possible to achieve the same in C# but you don't get the same syntactic sugar, so it's a bit ugly: `where LikeOperator.LikeString(mySourceString, "*Something*", CompareMethod.Text)`

It's in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices` namespace.

Further info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.likeoperator.likestring(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To get the most equivalent functionality ensure your C# project has a reference to the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly.

You can then directly use the VB.NET `Like` operator from your C#, e.g.

```
LikeOperator.LikeString(gme.element_key_name, "*web", CompareMethod.Text);
```

Be sure to include the

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices;
```

This will get the most equivalent functionality, however would be what I consider a bit of a hack.

Your other options would be to make use of the [`String.StartsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith(v=vs.110).aspx), [`String.EndsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith(v=vs.110).aspx), [`String.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) or [Regex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 5):

Use [`StartsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.startswith) or [`EndsWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.endswith) or [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa) static methods of `string` based on your needs.

Comment: Those methods don't allow for wildcard characters the way Like does

Comment: Also those are not static methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think Regex is the best option. Since the Like operation supports *,?, # and [],
I think there can be complex patterns possible which can be matched easily using the Regex library. For eg. the following lines will return true.

`"aBBBa" Like "a*a"
"ajhfgZ1" Like "*Z[12]"`

Now it depends on your application. If you are just using it to match a simple hardcoded string , you can directly use String.Contains, String,StartsWith or String.EndsWith but for complex matching use Regex for the best results.

Comment: You should probably add the actual regexes that you suggest. If you're trying to say `*Z[12]` is a regular expression, that's wrong. `a*a` also doesn't match `aBBBa`--it only matches 0 or more `a`s then another `a`. You may have meant `a.*a` and `Z[12]`. (Or you may have only been trying to demonstrate Like syntax, but this is unclear to me.)

Comment: hiii the a*a does match aBBBa . And the the the "Like" operation matches patterns with strings, so the pattern part of the equation does support * , ? and etc. and *Z[12] can be converted to a regular expression i meant, but for LIKE operation that is the way it can be used. More info on this is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx Anyways feel free to correct me if I'm wrong. Thats how i'll learn :)

Comment: Ok, my complaint is really just that it's unclear what your example means. `which can be matched easily using the Regex library. For eg. the following lines will return true.` leads me to believe the next few lines will have regular expressions. Pointing out that you're giving the examples just to show that Like is complex would clear it up I think.

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by others there is no Like operator in C#.

Also it is not available in VB.Net for .net standard. (It has been added again for .net)

I had the case that the pattern is a user input. Migrating to net standard, my only option was therefor to implement it myself. I chose to convert the pattern to an equivalent regular expression:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function VbLike(str As String, pattern As String) As Boolean
    Dim resultPattern = New Text.StringBuilder
    Dim insideList = False
    Dim prevInsideList = False
    For i = 0 To pattern.Length - 1
        Dim c = pattern(i)
        Dim tempInsideList = insideList

        ' Manage pattern start
        If i = 0 AndAlso c <> "*"c Then
            resultPattern.Append("^"c)
        End If

        ' Manage characterlists
        If c = "["c AndAlso Not insideList Then
            insideList = True
            resultPattern.Append(c)
        ElseIf c = "]"c AndAlso insideList Then
            insideList = False
            resultPattern.Append(c)

            ' Special chars for Like that need to be converted
        ElseIf c = "!"c AndAlso insideList AndAlso Not prevInsideList Then
            resultPattern.Append("^"c)
        ElseIf c = "?"c AndAlso Not insideList Then
            resultPattern.Append("."c)
        ElseIf c = "#"c AndAlso Not insideList Then
            resultPattern.Append("\d")
        ElseIf c = "*"c AndAlso i = 0 Then
            ' Nothing to append
        ElseIf c = "*"c AndAlso i = pattern.Length - 1 Then
            ' Nothing to append
        ElseIf c = "*"c AndAlso Not insideList Then
            resultPattern.Append(".*")

            ' Special chars for Regex that need to be escaped
        ElseIf c = "."c OrElse c = "\"c OrElse c = "("c OrElse c = ")"c Then
            resultPattern.Append("\"c)
            resultPattern.Append(c)
        Else
            resultPattern.Append(c)
        End If

        ' Manage pattern end
        If i = pattern.Length - 1 AndAlso c <> "*"c Then
            resultPattern.Append("$"c)
        End If

        prevInsideList = tempInsideList
    Next

    Return Regex.IsMatch(str, resultPattern.ToString, RegexOptions.Singleline Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase Or RegexOptions.CultureInvariant)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is Eric Pitz' VbLike code converted to C#, because the original poster was trying to re-create this function in C#.

```
public bool VbLike(string str, string pattern)
{
    var resultPattern = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    var insideList = false;
    var prevInsideList = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < pattern.Length; i++)
    {
        var c = pattern[i];
        var tempInsideList = insideList;

        // Manage pattern start
        if (i == 0 && c != '*')
        {
            resultPattern.Append('^');
        }

        // Manage characterlists
        if (c == '[' && !insideList)
        {
            insideList = true;
            resultPattern.Append(c);
        }
        else if (c == ']' && insideList)
        {
            insideList = false;
            resultPattern.Append(c);
        }
        else if (c == '!' && insideList && !prevInsideList)
        {
            // Special chars for Like that need to be converted
            resultPattern.Append('^');
        }
        else if (c == '?' && !insideList)
        {
            resultPattern.Append('.');
        }
        else if (c == '#' && !insideList)
        {
            resultPattern.Append(@"\d");
        }
        else if (c == '*' && i == 0)
        {
            // Nothing to append
        }
        else if (c == '*' && i == pattern.Length - 1)
        {
            // Nothing to append
        }
        else if (c == '*' && !insideList)
        {
            resultPattern.Append(".*");
        }
        else if (c == '.' || c == '\\' || c == '(' || c == ')')
        {
            // Special chars for Regex that need to be escaped
            resultPattern.Append('\\');
            resultPattern.Append(c);
        }
        else
        {
            resultPattern.Append(c);
        }

        // Manage pattern end
        if (i == pattern.Length - 1 && c != '*')
        {
            resultPattern.Append('$');
        }

        prevInsideList = tempInsideList;
    }

    return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(str, resultPattern.ToString(), System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.Singleline | System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is just as inapplicable as the answer you refer to, because the question is obviously about LINQ-to-SQL, where `Regex.IsMatch` is not supported.