# Variable search criteria function WinForms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am working on a project for class and have run into a problem. The app I am making is designed to log brews for a brewery using the criteria "Recipe", "Brewer" and "Date". I have everything working just fine except for my search function. I am trying to allow the user to search brew logs based of any criteria. For example, if you wanted to search all the logs for a specific recipe, you would just select that recipe from a drop down menu. This works just fine, however if I add more specificity like adding a brewer or date criteria, the function does not work.
This is the function I am using to determine the selected search criteria:

```
//funtion to determin what search criteria is being used and calling getResults() method
public string criteriaSort()
{
    string result = "";

    if (recipeCriteria.SelectedItem != null && brewerCriteria.SelectedItem == null & dateCriteria.Text == "")
    {
        string recipe = recipeCriteria.SelectedItem.ToString();
        result = getResults(recipe);
        return result;
    }
    else if (recipeCriteria.SelectedItem == null && brewerCriteria.SelectedItem != null & dateCriteria.Text == "")
    {
        string brewer = brewerCriteria.SelectedItem.ToString();
        result = getResults(brewer);
        return result;
    }
    else if (recipeCriteria.SelectedItem == null && brewerCriteria.SelectedItem == null & dateCriteria.Text != null)
    {
        string date = dateCriteria.Text;
        result = getResults(date);
        return result;
    }
    else if (recipeCriteria.SelectedItem != null && brewerCriteria.SelectedItem != null && dateCriteria.Text == null)
    {
        string recipe = recipeCriteria.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string brewer = brewerCriteria.SelectedItem.ToString();
        result = getResults(recipe, brewer);
        return result;
    }
    else if (recipeCriteria.SelectedItem != null && brewerCriteria.SelectedItem == null & dateCriteria.Text != null)
    {
        string recipe = recipeCriteria.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string date = dateCriteria.Text;
        result = getResults(recipe, date);
        return result;
    }
    else if (recipeCriteria.SelectedItem == null && brewerCriteria.SelectedItem != null && dateCriteria.Text != null)
    {
        string brewer = brewerCriteria.SelectedItem.ToString();
        string date = dateCriteria.Text;
        result = getResults(brewer, date);
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        result = getResults(recipeCriteria.SelectedItem.ToString(), brewerCriteria.SelectedItem.ToString(), dateCriteria.Text);
        return result;
    }
}
```

I am passing the selected criteria to overloaded methods depending on how many search options were chosen.

Here is an example of the methods used to return search results:

```
//overloaded method to take 3 search criterias
public string getResults(string criteria1, string criteria2, string criteria3)
{
    List<List<string>> brewLogList = brewLogs_ListOFlists();

    List<List<string>> searchResults = new List<List<string>>();

    string formatedSearchResults = "";

    foreach (List<string> log in brewLogList)
    {
        if (log.Contains(criteria1) && log.Contains(criteria2) && log.Contains(criteria3))
        {
            searchResults.Add(log);
        }
    }

    if (searchResults.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (List<string> log in searchResults)
        {
            formatedSearchResults += log[0] + ", " + log[1] + ", " + log[2];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        formatedSearchResults = "No brew log found matching that criteria";
    }

    return formatedSearchResults;
}
```

When using more than one search criteria I get no results found even when I know there is a result that should have been returned.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: When you step through the code in a debugger, can you indicate specifically what it does and which operation in the code first produces an unexpected result?

Comment: Side note, I see lots of repetitive code in your `if` statements (`criteriaSort`), IMHO, I would look at refactoring this...

Comment: I am not seeing anything abnormal when debugging. To be honest, I am brand new to programming so I may not be using it correctly.  Also in response to @zaggler comment, It felt repetitive when I was coding it but I'm not sure what a better way would be. Should I be storing the variable search options in boolean variables?

Comment: You might want to implement [the like operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24812880/380384) to be able to do pattern matching in strings.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.Where()` clause from `System.Linq`.

I have some test code that defines 4 brewers, 6 recipes, and 100 random brews

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AddBrewer("Joe");
    AddBrewer("Jack");
    AddBrewer("Jess");
    AddBrewer("Jen");

    AddRecipe("Pilzner A");
    AddRecipe("Pilzner B");
    AddRecipe("Blonde A");
    AddRecipe("Red A");
    AddRecipe("Dark A");
    AddRecipe("Dark B");

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        MakeBrew(rng.Next(4), rng.Next(6), RandomDate(2017, 2019));
    }

    // Example, find all Reds from 2019
    foreach (var item in Filter(recipie:"Red*", date: "2019*" ))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
        //[Red A] Joe 2019 August 03
        //[Red A] Joe 2019 September 22
        //[Red A] Jen 2019 February 27
        //[Red A] Jess 2019 April 21
        //[Red A] Jen 2019 November 08
    }
}
```

So this magic `Filter()` method filters all the brews in three steps (layers). The `Where()` function (defined under `System.Linq.Enumerable.Where()` as an extension method to `IEnumerable<T>`) filters a collection based on custom criteria.

```
public static IEnumerable<Brew> Filter(string brewer = null, string recipie = null, string date = null)
{
    var result = brews.AsEnumerable();
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(date))
    {
        result = result.Where((item) => LikeOperator.LikeString(item.Date.ToString(Brew.DateFormat), date, CompareMethod.Text));
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(brewer))
    {                
        result = result.Where((item) => LikeOperator.LikeString(item.Brewer.Name, brewer, CompareMethod.Text));
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(recipie))
    {
        result = result.Where((item) => LikeOperator.LikeString(item.Recipe.Name, recipie, CompareMethod.Text));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Notice that I am using the [**`LikeOperator`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.likeoperator.likestring?view=net-5.0) from the `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` assembly. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24812880/380384) for more details.