# VB.NET LIKE string comparison operator equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm a new developer in C# and I'm migrating code from VB.NET to C#. But the LIKE operator is not working in C#, is there another one with the same function?

The VB.NET code I need to convert looks like this::

```
If (item Like "[A-D]") Then

    End If

    If (item Like "[E-H]") Then

    End If

    If (item Like "[I-M]") Then

    End If

    If (item Like "[N-V]") Then

    End If
```

Comment: The closest equivalent is probably `Regex.IsMatch`

Comment: BTW, what kinds of string values does `item` have? Is it always a single-character string?

Comment: `LikeOperator` https://stackoverflow.com/a/24812880/9925593

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.compilerservices.likeoperator.likestring?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LIKE operator does not exist for C#, the solution is to use regular expression.

try this:

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(item, "^[a-dA-D]+$"))
        {

        }

        if (Regex.IsMatch(item, "^[e-hE-H]+$"))
        {

        }

        if (Regex.IsMatch(item, "^[i-mI-M]+$"))
        {

        }

        if (Regex.IsMatch(item, "^[n-vN-V]+$"))
        {

        }
```

Comment: If you use `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` then you can simplfy those patterns to just `"^[A-D]$"` - note that VB.NET's `Like` operator uses `[A-B]` to denote a **single** character, so using the one-or-more quantifier (`+`) will result in different behaviour compared to `Like` (`"AD"` won't match `Like "[A-D]"` but will match `Regex.IsMatch( item, "^[A-D]+$" )`.